# How can I login to phpBB3 forum programmatically by Java code?

Tags: java

I googled and found [this](http://www.1your.com/drupal/LoginToWebsiteByHTTPPOST) article but it didn't work with phpBB.

Would you mind giving me any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For it to work, the phpBB code would have to be looking for POSTed login credentials, which may not be the case. phpBB would need to specifically look for a post variable named user_name and user_pass which again may not be the case.

The example you are following is more a tutorial for using the POST method in HTTP from Java. If you want to see the results try it with the page they posted in the article located at http://www.1your.com/drupal/sample_login.php

As a suggestion, you could use something like [Firebug](http://www.getfirebug.com) to analyze the request/response HTTP transaction and from there you know what phpBB is expecting at the server side.